# Select records where at least some has_many relations are in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I have activities which have_many events - events are the date and time the activities occur.

In my activities index, I want to list all activities that have at least one event in the future.

I'm using ransack to do my other filtering , suck as categories etc.

How can i filter for a greater than condition accross a relation?

I thought I would be able to do:

```
obj = search
        .joins(:event)
        .where(:events => ['end_at > ?', Date.today ])
```

but i get an error:

```
undefined method `join' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007f8aa8eff918>
```

**UPDATE**
so to give more context, my controler looks like this

```
def index            
    if (params[:oldestchild].present? && params[:oldestchild].to_i > 0) ||   
      (params[:youngestchild].present? && params[:youngestchild].to_i > 0)
      @search = Activity
       .where(' (oldest > ?z and youngest < ?) or (oldest > ? and youngest < ?) ', 
         params[:oldestchild], params[:oldestchild],
         params[:youngestchild], params[:youngestchild], 
         )
       .search(params[:q])
    else
       @search = Activity
         .search(params[:q])
    end  

    @activities = Activity.filter(params, @search, request).includes(:provider).includes(:location)

    if current_parent and current_parent.children.first
      @min_child_age = current_parent.min_child_age 
      @max_child_age = current_parent.max_child_age
    end
end
```

and my model has this filter method:

```
  def self.filter(params, search, request)          
        obj = search.result(:distinct => true)      
#       obj = search
#               .joins(:event)
#               .where(:events => ['end_at > ?', Date.today ])      

    if params[:within].present? && (params[:within].to_i > 0)
          obj = obj.where(:location_id => self.build_locations_array(request))
        end                         
        if  params[:q].present? and params[:q][:category_ids].present? 
            obj = obj
            .joins(:categories)
            .where('categories.id' => params[:q][:category_ids])                                                                        
        end
        if params[:date_range] == "This month"              
            obj = obj.where(:start => (Date.today)..(Date.today.at_end_of_month))   
        end

        if params[:date_range] == "Next month"  
            date = Date.today + 1.month             
            obj = obj.where(:start => (date.at_beginning_of_month)..(date.at_end_of_month))                                                                     
        end
        if params[:date_range] == "Next 3 Months"               
            date = Date.today + 3.month             
            obj = obj.where(:start => (Date.today)..(date.at_end_of_month))                                                                     
        end
        if params[:date_range] == "Whenever"             
            obj = obj.where("start > ?",  Date.today)                                                                       
        end 

        obj.paginate(:page => params[:page],  :per_page => 5)               
  end
```

UPATE

one option that is working, but is fairly ugly is to use sql.

```
obj = search.result(:distinct => true)
 .where("exists (select events.id from events 
          where events.activity_id = activities.id 
          and end_at > ?)", Date.today)
```

Comment: Can you just give few more details like, where is this bit of code from? (Model or controller?)

Comment: Nothing is going to perform as well as the SQL solution, unless it generates that code. Activerecord could really do with support for EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Solution seems to be simple: remove search(params[:q]) from if else statement and use it after your Activity.filter call (or after includes if they  also throw same error).

Or, maybe better:

```
obj = search.result(:distinct => true).joins(:event).where(:events => ['end_at > ?', Date.today ])
```

Comment: hmm, that snippet is as i had it, it gives an error "Association named 'event' was not found" because i guess activities has_many events, not event.  switching to plural though gives "PG::Error: ERROR:  column activities.events does not exist
LINE 1: ... "events"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" WHERE "activitie"